# IE8 button gets "stuck down" when mouseup event is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a `<button>` with a nested image and I'm using jQuery to toggle the image `src` attribute on `mousedown` and `mouseup`. When the button is clicked in IE8 the image moves down and right 1 pixel, as buttons do in IE, but then it sticks there and won't return to its original position. If I remove the `mouseup` event the button functions normally, but of course my js button behavior breaks.

In googling the issue I have found another bug that causes a button with a CSS background to move up and left when `active`, but then return. My button gets stuck, and only when there is a `mouseup` event registered.

The markup looks like this:

html:

```
<button type="button" id="sdbSearchButton" title="Zoom to this room">
    <img id="sdbSearchButtonImg" src="images/control_play.gif" />
</button>
```

CSS:

```
label.sdbAttr button {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

javascript:

```
$('#sdbSearchButton').mousedown(function(e) {
    $(this).children().attr('src', 'images/control_play_blue.gif');
    searchForSpace();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children().attr('src', 'images/control_play.gif');
}).mouseup(function() {
    $(this).children().attr('src', 'images/control_play.gif');
});
```

Comment: What happens when you load the same webpage in other browsers?

Comment: I checked it in Firefox, but FF doesn't shift buttons like IE does so its kind of moot. Neither the button in question or other ones on the page shift in FF. In IE other with the same markup but no `mouseup` event shift when active, then shift back. When shifted the image gets clipped, regardless of the CSS `overflow` value for the button. To prevent this I will probably apply the workaround suggested for the bug I mentioned, which prevents them from moving, but I don't think it will solve my sticky image. I may just ditch the image swap effect. Curious if anyone else has experienced this tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using an img?

```
button {
background-image: url('img1')
}
button:active {
background-image: url('img2')
}
```

Comment: Ah, KISS. This project is long over though. I'll remember this for next time.